# Why is Microsoft discouraging the public/protected return of named tuples in C# 7?

Tags: c#

According to the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/csharp-7) under Ref locals and returns:

> There are many issues with this code. First of all, it's a public method that's returning a tuple. The language supports this, but user defined types (either classes or structs) are preferred for public APIs.

They have an example on the same document that shows a private method returning a named tuple.

Prior to C#7 we only had the Tuple<> struct which for obvious reasons was inadequate for public consumption. Personally I have no problem using them within the scope of a method and strongly advocate they are never returned from a method, even a private one. However even that view point has been virulently opposed by many in the community who believe that Tuple<> should have never made it into the .NET Framework to begin with.

A named struct provides semantics, which Tuple<> was of course lacking, and provides the caller with a description of the values being returned, because of this I'm finding myself thinking that there are many scenarios where I could advocate the use of these named Tuples in a public API. If the data being returned by an API call does not have further use within the API there does not seem to be an architectural need for a concrete class or struct.

Are there performance, memory or other considerations that I am missing that would lead Microsoft to make such a statement in their documentation?

Comment: I would imagine it's because you're assuming the consumer is also using C#7, which may not be the case. It's all syntactic sugar, so someone using C#6, for example, would merely see a public `Tuple<>`

Comment: Great point, you should post that in that as an answer so I can mark it

Comment: @JasonLind, If you have mixed up logins and want to use your previous account, use the [contact us](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) link and get the accounts merged. In this way you'll save the rep earned from both the different accounts.

Comment: Great advice, thank you